# Deep link does not work if app is already open

Tags: android, webview

If my app is already open, clicking on any link received on mail, Whatsapp open my app- but does not open the link clicked.

With the app killed, It can open the app and route to the correct activity, no problem.

However, if I click on another link again, without killing the app, It would only open the app, but it will not open the correct activity.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="app.freeairdrop.io">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <application
        android:appCategory="productivity"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name=".ApplicationClass"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity
            android:name="app.freeairdrop.io.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout"
            android:resizeableActivity="false"
            android:supportsPictureInPicture="false"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="freeairdrop.io" />
            </intent-filter>


        </activity>
    </application>


    </manifest>
```

Comment: hi , were you able to find any solution to this ? I am facing same kind of issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `launchMode="singleInstance"`.

This would indicate that you only want *one* instance of the Activity, which means if a deeplink is triggered when that activity already exists, it would just route to that existing instance.